# Does eating Nestle Fitness Cereal for weight loss require other nutrition?

Tags: weight-loss

There is a cereal claiming to help me lose weight if I eat it.

[image: Nestle Fitness Cereal]

[This blog post is all about this production](http://www.tryingtobefahad.com/2010/11/product-review-nestle-fitness-cereal/).
A short summary of it:

> Nestle Fitness Cereal Health Claims:
>   - Contains Fiber
>
> - Less than 1.5% Saturated Fat
> - Source of Vitamins
> - Contains Whole Grain
> - Delicious
>
> Each Nestle Fitness Box contains 375g of [supposedly] whole-grain goodness. Here’s the breakdown of those 375g:
>
> **Calories:** 1,395
>
> - **Carbohydrates:** 294 grams
> - **Sugars:** 64.5 grams (22% sugar from total carbohydrate amount)
> - **Fiber:** 22.125 grams (0.075% from total carbohydrate amount)
> - **Fat:** 5.25 grams
> - **Protein:** 31.5 grams
>
> **Ingredients:** Whole Grain Wheat, Rice, Sugar, Partially Inverted Brown Sugar, Sugar Syrup, Barley Malt Extract, Salt, Glucose Syrup, Vitamins & Minerals.

Does the body require any other nutritional needs (such as from fruit) if someone is eating this cereal?

Comment: I suggest adding information to this question from the link you posted so that everything can be viewed in one place in case the linked website goes away or changes over time.

Comment: FWIW... that is a TON of carbohydrates! My 1800 calorie daily intake has less than 100g of carbs (and 3x the protein, which helps my appetite and super huge muscles). But I'm just a stranger on the internet... :)

Comment: @TheChaz: A stranger? Not really. I know you, you're a student and a teacher.

Comment: And a lover, and a warrior...

Comment: @TheChaz - That's for the whole box. Recommended serving is 30g.

Comment: I remember this thread... but had no idea that you were the OP, Gigili! And my first comment should read: "...that is 1/10 of a TON of carbohydrates!"

Comment: @TheChaz: I have no idea why I'd leave a comment like that. Not that I'm interested in talking to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weight loss is still poorly understood.

What's certain is that if you starve yourself, you will lose weight, and if you massively overeat for a sustained period of time, you will gain weight. Everything in between is less predictable. Our body isn't stupid, if it detects an imbalance it will correct it.

Eating only this cereal might make you thin, or it might make you fat. It might also make you deficient in whatever this cereal doesn't provide.

One of the ideas gaining popularity is that human beings aren't broken by default, and that something about our diet causes our body to get overweight (and eventually sick). Exactly what causes it is unknown, but large doses of wheat, fructose and Omega-6 poly-unsaturated fats as well as highly processed foods have been fingered as the culprits. Paleo dieters avoid these things (and call them *Neolithic Agents of Disease* :-) ) and the body returns to a more natural equilibrium.

Personally, I first lost weight and then gained muscle and energy avoiding these NADs, without counting calories so I'm convinced that my regular diet was not healthy. I ate mostly a standard american diet with an extra helping of sweets.

This cereal doesn't look too highly processed, but personally I wouldn't eat it because of the wheat content and because there are so many other foods that are much yummier.

Comment: Weight loss is not poorly understood, except maybe by you. We have made massive strides in the advancement of our biochemical and pharmacokinetic understanding of the human body and metabolic pathways.

Comment: Seriously, how does that comment help?

Comment: Just bringing a little bit of reality to your life buddy.

Answer (score 3):

Eating anything will help you lose weight if you don't eat much of it.

If you were to eat nothing but that cereal, given the most conservative estimate of 0.5 grams of protein per pound of body weight per day required to maintain muscle - a 150lb human would require 75 grams of protein. To get that from the cereal you would need to eat 892 grams of the cereal - almost 2 1/2 packets.

This would also give you 700 grams of carbohydrates, 153 grams of sugar and 3321 calories.

This is what is required for a sedentary person - an active person would need more protein so would have to eat more.

You would get fat.

Comment: And that would be if you eat it without milk. On the other side, milk contains alot of proteins, which would reduce the amount of cereal needed. So this depends highly on the cereal-to-milk ratio prefered

Answer (score -3):

I believe that Nestle Hole wheat flakes with honey and almond is a balanced diet because it has carbohydrate , vitamins and proteins. i found it effective because its quite filling and i stopped craving for food after eating Nestle fitness cereals and of course it complemented weight loss without any difficulty. busy people like us can go for Nestle both for fitness and weight loss.

Comment: Can you provide a more thorough explanation of why?